# Regex process logfiles with multiline and ungreedy flags

Tags: regex

The logfile I am trying to match contains different severities with different outputs. Some logs are oneline and some are multilines with a lot of debug information included.
The regex I have finds all the entries, but for multilines stops matching at the newline character. The environment is Ungreedy.

```
^\[(?<type>\w+):(?<severity>\w+),(?<timestamp>\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+Z),(?<node_name>[^:]*):([^:]+):(?<source>[^\]]+)\](?<message>.*)$
```

One log starts either at [error_logger...] or at [ns_server...]. The last group of the log is the "message" group and that should finish until the next occurrence of another log (error_logger OR ns_server). In this example are 3 different logs where the one-lines are matched correctly, while the one with multiline (which contains INFO REPORT or JSON Payload) is not.

```
[ns_server:debug,2022-06-30T23:52:17.409Z,ns_1@vm-1.c.server_name.internal:compaction_daemon<0.476.0>:compaction_scheduler:schedule_next:60]Finished compaction for compact_views too soon. Next run will be in 30s
[error_logger:info,2022-06-30T23:52:17.765Z,ns_1@vm-1.c.server_name.internal:error_logger<0.32.0>:ale_error_logger_handler:do_log:203]
=========================INFO REPORT=========================
{net_kernel,{connect,normal,
                     'ns_1@vm-2.c.server_name.internal'}}
[ns_server:info,2022-06-30T23:52:18.405Z,ns_1@vm-1.c.server_name.internal:<0.821.0>:ns_orchestrator:handle_info:523]Skipping janitor in state janitor_running
```

Here is the test with some examples of the logs I need to process: https://regex101.com/r/HyiWIy/1
It already has the flags global, multiline and ungreedy set.

***Background***: The logs are read from Google Cloud OPS Agent and pushed to the Cloud Logging in GCP. Cloud OPS Agent is using fluent bit for logs and metrics. Out of all different combinations I have tried, the agent matches exactly the entries that are matched in the provided example.
Using a modifier like this: (?-U) crashes the fluent-bit service, so that is not the way I'd like to go.

In the screenshot you can see that the first line is processed fine until a newline. After that, every line of the unmatched block is processed separately and counts as a separate log line (although it's not)

[image: Log Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a non-greedy message-capturing group that can cross linefeeds in a multi-line regex (. does not match \n in multi-line regex) and a positive look-ahead to identify the end of the message.

This regex should do what needs to be done:

`^\[(?<type>\w+):(?<severity>\w+),(?<timestamp>\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+Z),(?<node_name>[^:]*):([^:]+):(?<source>[^\]]+)\](?<message>[\s\S]*?)(?=\n\[ns_server:|\n\[error_logger:|\Z)`

The trick here is the `[\s\S]*?` to capture the message. It is a non-greedy term that can even in multi-line-mode go across newline characters. Non-greedy is necessary for it to not run over the beginning of the next log-entry that is found by the last parenthesised term: a positive look-ahead that identifies either the start of a new log-entry or the end of the file (\Z). Since it is a look-ahead, it does not consume the next log-entry's start, so it can still be used for the next match.

Look here https://regex101.com/r/qsmEQO/1 to see the regex in action.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make the environment ungreedy, and in the `message` group repeat matching all lines until the next line that starts with for example `[` word chars and `:`

```
^\[(?<type>\w+):(?<severity>\w+),(?<timestamp>\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+Z),(?<node_name>[^:]*):([^:]+):(?<source>[^\]]+)\](?<message>.*(?:\n(?!\[\w+:).*)*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SvJggD/1)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I have tried similar approach and just tried your posted answer, but the issue is that the environment does match those logs with "info report" or those with json debug information. As a result, for an info report with e.g., 100 lines, it puts 100 broken entries in the logging dashboard. 
Quick recap: it matches exactly the same results as when I set the flag to ungreedy.

Comment: @Xhens Are the matches in the regex demo not the expected matches? Note that if you enable the Ungreedy flag, then the optional repetition at the end of the group will not match the additional lines. Can you update the regex101 link with example data that does not match?

Comment: It is already in the URL I posted: https://regex101.com/r/HyiWIy/1 Everything that is not matched here, is also not matched in the real environment.

Comment: @Xhens What is the tool or language where you are using the pattern? So when you use disable the non greedy flag you get the same  results just matching a single line? Do you want the `=========================INFO REPORT=========================` part being part of the message?

Comment: I'm using it for the Google Cloud OPS Agent. It is built in Golang as far as I've seen in Github. I want the INFO REPORT inside the message. Basically, in order to configure the logging I have to provide a regex and the file path to the OPS Agent.

Comment: @Xhens Golang does not support lookaround assertions, but if you still get a result I am not sure if the pattern is also used in Golang. If you want to disable the ungeedy behaviour you might use an inline modifier. Are you sure that it processes all lines at once? If it processes line by line then perhaps processing multiple lines with the pattern does not work. See https://regex101.com/r/45wbsh/1 with an inline modifier https://regex101.com/r/45wbsh/1

Comment: I think there is some limitation on the server side. Setting this: (?-U) actually crashed the fluent-bit service. I can see that you posted the same link twice. Was that by mistake or did I miss any detail? I think I am left only with line-by-line processing to try.

Comment: @Xhens No... you are not. Look at my answer. ;-)