# Fluentd Multiline Parser with regex option is not parsing correctly

Tags: regex, multiline, fluentd

Trying to parse the below log message in fluentd multiline parser with regexp options. But I am able to parse it successfully, even though the [online regex editor](https://regex101.com/r/WGKThf/1) is able to parse it successfully.

**Sample logs**

```
2023-03-09T12:40:35.135000+00:00
IOD_SESS.monitor begin:2023-03-09T12:40:32.856 end:2023-03-09T12:40:33.134 interval:+000000000 00:00:00.278381000 monitored_sessions:0 killed_sessions:0
2023-03-09T12:40:35 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) begin
2023-03-09T12:40:35 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) end (rows:2)
2023-03-09T12:41:40.135000+00:00
IOD_SESS.monitor begin:2023-03-09T12:40:32.856 end:2023-03-09T12:40:33.134 interval:+000000000 00:00:00.278381000 monitored_sessions:0 killed_sessions:0
2023-03-09T12:41:40 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) begin
2023-03-09T12:41:40 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) end (rows:2)
2023-03-09T12:42:35.135000+00:00
IOD_SESS.monitor begin:2023-03-09T12:40:32.856 end:2023-03-09T12:40:33.134 interval:+000000000 00:00:00.278381000 monitored_sessions:0 killed_sessions:0
2023-03-09T12:42:35 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) begin
2023-03-09T12:42:35 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) end (rows:2)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WGKThf/1) parser is able to parse it correctly. But when I use this same parser with the below configuration in `td-agent.conf` in fluentd. It says that the pattern is not matched.

**td-agent.conf**

```xml
<source>
  @type tail
  path /tmp/gg.txt
  read_from_head true
  tag db
  <parse>
  @type regexp
  expression /^(?<timestamp>)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}\+\d{2}:\d{2}(?<message>.*(?:\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}\+\d{2}:\d{2}).*)*)/gm
  </parse>
</source>

<match db>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

No messages are parsed and the output looks like this:

```
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=42838 ppid=42836 worker=0
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [info]: #0 following tail of /tmp/gg.txt
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "IOD_SESS.monitor begin:2023-03-09T12:40:32.856 end:2023-03-09T12:40:33.134 interval:+000000000 00:00:00.278381000 monitored_sessions:0 killed_sessions:0"
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "2023-03-09T12:40:35 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) begin"
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "2023-03-09T12:40:35 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) end (rows:2)"
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "IOD_SESS.monitor begin:2023-03-09T12:40:32.856 end:2023-03-09T12:40:33.134 interval:+000000000 00:00:00.278381000 monitored_sessions:0 killed_sessions:0"
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "2023-03-09T12:41:40 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) begin"
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "2023-03-09T12:41:40 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) end (rows:2)"
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "IOD_SESS.monitor begin:2023-03-09T12:40:32.856 end:2023-03-09T12:40:33.134 interval:+000000000 00:00:00.278381000 monitored_sessions:0 killed_sessions:0"
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "2023-03-09T12:42:35 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) begin"
2023-03-12 23:12:31 +0530 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "2023-03-09T12:42:35 (IOD_SESS.snap_blocked_sessions) end (rows:2)"
2023-03-12 23:12:31.893575000 +0530 db: {"timestamp":"","message":""}
2023-03-12 23:12:31.893900000 +0530 db: {"timestamp":"","message":""}
2023-03-12 23:12:31.894040000 +0530 db: {"timestamp":"","message":""
```

Comment: You misplaced closing parenthesis near `<timestamp>)`. I believe it should be right before `(?<message>`

Comment: Also, judging by provided log it looks to me like parsing is line-by-line. So even when you'll correct capturing of group named `timestamp` you will only see timestamp in your logs. You should investigate possibility to parse multiple lines of log.

Comment: Thanks @markalex . Closing parenthesis fixed the time stamp issue. But i could not why the regex able to parse and identify 3 messages correctly, but fluentd could not. I was taking the reference from this page to write regex parser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72935884/regex-process-logfiles-with-multiline-and-ungreedy-flags/73070339#73070339 . However im not an expert in writing regex, could you please help me on what needs to be corrected here for parsing multiple line log messages. Updated regex: https://regex101.com/r/TYMfcl/1

Comment: @Hariprasad: Did you try using [`multiline`](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline) instead of `regexp`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with fluentd, but it seems to me that it parses lines separately. And in your example in lines 1, 4 and 7 it finds timestamp and an empty message. Other lines don't match your regex, so it finds nothing in them. You could try and find a way to parse multiple lines as one entry, or try the multiline plugin as Azeem recommended, it seems to do exactly what is needed for this case.

Comment: I tried in the past with multiline, but could not able to parse the log lines. Now i can able to parse it  now. `<parse>
  @type multiline
  format_firstline /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}\+\d{2}:\d{2}/
  format1 /^(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}\+\d{2}:\d{2})/
  format2 /(?<msg>.*)/
</parse>`